# selecting a nested object based on nested dropdowns with knockoutjs

Tags: json, knockout.js

ok so i have the following json:

```
{"VehicleMakes":
[{"VehicleModels":[],"ID":3,"Description":"BMW"},
{"VehicleModels":[],"ID":1,"Description":"Ford"},
{"VehicleModels":[{"ID":1,"Description":"Astra","MakeID":2},{"ID":2,"Description":"Corsa","MakeID":2}],"ID":2,"Description":"Vauxhall"}],
"VehicleModels":[],
"SelectedMake":"Vauxhall","SelectedModel":null,"Postcode":null}
```

So basically I have a few vehicle makes and a make can have a number of models.

I then have the following model:

```
 function SearchModel() {
        this.SearchCriteria = "";
        this.SelectedMake = ko.observable();
        this.SelectedModel = ko.observable();
    }
```

And then this html:

```
<select id="vehiclesMake" data-bind="options: SearchCriteria.VehicleMakes, optionsText: 'Description',optionsValue: 'Description', value: SelectedMake, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>      

 <div data-bind="if: SelectedMake">
            <select data-bind='options: SelectedMake().VehicleModels, optionsText: "Description", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "Description", value: SelectedModel'></select>
                 </div>
```

So I am basically trying to say, when a vehicle make is  selected in the first dropdown, display its models in the 2nd dropdown.

The first dropdown populates fine and when I make a selection the 2nd dropdown appears but isn't being populated.

Note I assign all the json to the property SearchCriteria.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first select with the setting `optionsValue: 'Description'` you tell knockout to use the `Description` text as the value in the select. So your `SelectedMake` will contain the `Description` text instead of the VehicleMake object.

So just remove the `optionsValue` and it should work fine:

```
<select id="vehiclesMake" data-bind="options: SearchCriteria.VehicleMakes, 
                                     optionsText:  'Description', 
                                     value: SelectedMake, 
                                     optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/QqzLA/).